# Fatal: Invalide path 'cygdrive/c/Users/dlittle/c:|Users\dlittle': No such file or directory on Win7 + Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

This just happened to me now. Here is what I did on my Win7 box:

1. Fresh re-install Cygwin
2. Put c:\cygwin\bin in win7 Path
3. In Win7 Command Prompt (cmd, not in cygwin), try to install Vundle.vim by:

   git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim

AND got:

```
fatal: Invalid path '/cygdrive/c/Users/dlittle/C:\Users\dlittel': No such file or directory
```

Obviously, %USERPROFILE% was NOT interpreted properly. But in the same CMD window, I do:

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
```

It gives correct result which is: `c:\Users\dlittle>`

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: My workaround is uninstall Cygwin GIT and Install Git Windows so that the Win GIT is the only one and in my Win7 PATH.